# how to move particular functionality to staging server

Tags: staging

I have local development environment, which i am using to development project in and once it is finished i need to move it to Staging server. Once it is confirmed from the client i need to move it to production.

Now my question is how can i move only specific change to staging server. If i changed files than i can move it staging but what if I change something from admin or install a new plugin?

Comment: Even if you install a new plugin or change something from admin you would notice the time stamp! Wouldn't you?

Comment: @sri you mean in table?

Comment: Yes in WordPress tables and also in the file system?